# java.security.AccessControlException:

Tags: java, oracle, applet, appletviewer

This may be old error but I am stuck here.

I created Java applet to access an Oracle database. I am going to put this applet in Local Network. My applet works fine in Eclipse and Netbeans but when I run through 'appletviewer' it goes at connection string and showing an error:

```
Error e java.security.AccessControlException: access denied (
    "java.util.PropertyPermission" "oracle.net.wallet_location" "read")
```

I already signed applet using this Oracle technique for [Signed Applets](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html).

I used the user of database who has full rights.  Also when I run using policy file, it shows the same error.

How do I connect the applet to the database successfully?

---

The HTML used to load the applet is:

```
<applet
    code=tree.pacg.DrawApplet.class
    codebase=c:\tree\pacg
    archive=DrawApplet.jar,ojdbc14.jar
    height="800"
    width="1000"> 
</applet>
```

Comment: when i run the applet in ie, it show security warning `Java has discovered application components that could indicate a secuirty concern.` I clicked on 'yes'. but then nothing display..

Comment: Sir, my total applet code is `<applet code=tree.pacg.DrawApplet.class codebase=c:\tree\pacg archive=DrawApplet.jar,ojdbc14.jar height="800" width="1000">
</applet>`

Comment: 1) `code` should be `tree.pacg.DrawApplet`.  2) `codebase` should be an URL, something like `file:C:///tree/pacg` 3) `ojdbc14.jar` needs to be digitally signed when deploying this way.  Is `ojdbc14.jar` digitally signed? 4) For best results, include all attributes in double quotes (").

Comment: 1) yes code is `tree.pacg.DrawApplet` 2) I put codebase in `file:/C:/tree/pacg` 3) `ojdbc14.jar` is a oracle database drivers so that they are already signed 4) I put all attributes value in double quotes... but the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its solved !!

I signed the ojdbc14.jar file and it works !!

also I create new policy file and gave it 'All' access permission then it also work through 'appletviewer'

Thanks..Thank you sir..

Comment: I would suggest you to add steps to solve in your answer and then accept it

Answer (score 1):

> when i run the applet in ie, it show security warning *Java has discovered application components that could indicate a secuirty concern.*

Something like this?

[image: Mixed code security warning]

BTW - if you click <kbd>**No**</kbd> at this point, the code should **not be blocked** and should therefore run.

But even seeing that dialog is a nuisance.  If it can be confusing to developers, it is bound to be confusing to an end user.

---

See [Mixing Signed and Unsigned Code
Ensuring Application and Applet Security](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html) for an explanation of this behavior.   But see particularly [Deploying Signed Applications and Applets Securely Without a Mixed Code Warning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html#manifest) for how to *allow mixing* of unsigned & signed code.

The other alternative - to sign all Jars using the same certificate - also works, but is sometimes forbidden by deployment licenses or other factors.

### On signing the code.

Me.

> 3) `ojdbc14.jar` needs to be digitally signed when deploying this way. Is `ojdbc14.jar` digitally signed?

OP.

> 3) ojdbc14.jar is a oracle database drivers so that they are already signed

..followed 4 hours later by..

> I signed the ojdbc14.jar file and it works !!

Comment: Note, if you click No to that dialog, you are effectively giving permissions to unsigned code.

Comment: See [here](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2013/03/19/java-has-discovered-application-components-that-could-indicate-a-security-concern/) for changing the Mixed Code setting programmatically